# Iterating a string in python in blocks

Tags: python

I have a string and I'm trying to iterate it in blocks and save the value of each block into a list, but, without success.

```
string_A = '920dfffffffff27aff024932090901212003024937090901212003024942090901212003024947090901212003'
newFileTtsInHexString = []
finalListFile = []
for element in string_A[0:len(string_A):18]:  
        newFileTtsInHexString = element
        print("\n=== newFileTtsInHexString ==="+newFileTtsInHexString)
        finalListFile = '\n'.join(newFileTtsInHexString)
```

that's the output :

```
=== newFileTtsInHexString ===9
=== newFileTtsInHexString ===0
=== newFileTtsInHexString ===0
=== newFileTtsInHexString ===0
=== newFileTtsInHexString ===0
```

But my goal is to have the finalListFile like this:

```
920dfffffffff27aff
024932090901212003
024937090901212003
024942090901212003
024947090901212003
```

in blocks of 18 characters.

Comment: Main problem is how you take the slice and for loop iteration through each element iterates character by character. ```for element in string_A[0:len(string_A):18]```. Slice [0:len(string_A):18] is "90000", for element in '90000' iterates through '9' '0' '0' '0' '0'. 
Slice [0:18] is the first chunk you want "920dfffffffff27aff".

Comment: Get rid of for loop, something like this instead of the for would work: ```while string_A:
        element = string_A[0:18]
        string_A = string_A[18:]
```

Comment: Not really a duplicate question, ... ~ sort of ~ ... as the unintended question(s) here are really on why doesn't ```for element in string_A[incorrectSlice]``` work? Issues are: 1. fixing slice, 2. iterating char by char, 3. program structure for iterating through the string in chunks.

Comment: How does slicing work? slice[start:stop] returns the chunk from start to stop. The manual is a bit, well, manuall-y  https://docs.python.org/2.5/ref/slicings.html   Interestingly the third stride argument was a later addition slice[start:stop:stride] https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html. I would say the stride is not used much.

Answer (score 4):

Is this wnat you want?

```
s = '920dfffffffff27aff024932090901212003024937090901212003024942090901212003024947090901212003'

print([s[i:i+18] for i in range(0, len(s), 18)])
```

Output:

```
['920dfffffffff27aff', '024932090901212003', '024937090901212003', '024942090901212003', '024947090901212003']
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not completely wrong, you need to do this differently:

```
string_A = '920dfffffffff27aff024932090901212003024937090901212003024942090901212003024947090901212003'
newFileTtsInHexString = []
finalListFile = []
for i in range(len(str)//18): # iterates through your string in blocks
    string = string_A # so we don't crush our string
    newFileTtsInHexString[i] = string[i*18:(i+1)*18] # get the substring and append to our list
    finalListFile = '\n'.join(newFileTtsInHexString)
```

Not tested, could contain errors.

Comment: hey Fabian, thanks, with some minors corrections, the code worked fine.